Consulta sobre diferencia de resultados en SQL
Estimad@s, buenos días, tengo un inconveniente. Tengo dos SP en SQL que deberían hacer lo mismo, pero la consulta es diferente. Están hechos para comparar datos, el caso es que por algún motivo hay dos campos que no coinciden.
Primer SP:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_L_ReportePagosElectronicos]
    @int_mes INT, 
    @int_ano INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE        #TempTipoPagosCantidad  (
                                                    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesEfectivo INT,
                                                    Float_ImporteEfectivo FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosEfectivo INT, 

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesDeposito INT,
                                                    Float_Deposito FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosDeposito INT,

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesPagoFacil INT,
                                                    Float_PagoFacil FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosPagoFacil INT,

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesDebito INT,
                                                    Float_Debito FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosDebito INT,

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesTarjetaNaranja INT,
                                                    Float_TarjetaNaranja FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosTarjetaNaranja INT,

                                                    Int_CantidadClientesPagos360 INT,
                                                    Float_Pagos360 FLOAT,
                                                    Int_CantidadTitulosPagos360  INT,
                                                )

    INSERT INTO         #TempTipoPagosCantidad  (
                                                    Int_CantidadClientesEfectivo
                                                    , Float_ImporteEfectivo
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosEfectivo

                                                    , Int_CantidadClientesDeposito
                                                    , Float_Deposito
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosDeposito

                                                    , Int_CantidadClientesPagoFacil
                                                    , Float_PagoFacil
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosPagoFacil

                                                    , Int_CantidadClientesDebito
                                                    , Float_Debito
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosDebito

                                                    , Int_CantidadClientesTarjetaNaranja
                                                    , Float_TarjetaNaranja
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosTarjetaNaranja

                                                    , Int_CantidadClientesPagos360
                                                    , Float_Pagos360
                                                    , Int_CantidadTitulosPagos360
                                                )

    SELECT 
                                                    --EFECTIVO
                                                    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'E' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesEfectivo
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'E' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_ImporteEfectivo
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'E' THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosEfectivo

                                                    --DEPÓSITO
                                                    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'D' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesDeposito
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'D' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_Deposito
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'D' THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosDeposito

                                                    --PAGO FÁCIL
                                                    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'P' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesPagoFacil
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'P' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_PagoFacil
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'P' THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosPagoFacil

                                                    --DÉBITO
                                                    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00086' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesDebito
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00086' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_Debito
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00086' THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosDebito

                                                    --TARJETA NARANJA
                                                    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00097' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesTarjetaNaranja
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00097' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_TarjetaNaranja
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.CobPor = '00097'THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosTarjetaNaranja

                                                    --PAGOS 360
                                                    , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'T' THEN CL.Id END) AS Int_CantidadClientesPagos360
                                                    , SUM(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'T' THEN ISNULL(C.IMPCOMPROB, 0) ELSE 0 END) AS Float_Pagos360
                                                    , COUNT(CASE WHEN C.Forma = 'T' THEN C.TITULO END) AS Int_CantidadTitulosPagos360
    
    FROM                CUESOLIC C
                            INNER JOIN 
                                PLANsql PLSQL
                                    ON 
                                        C.CODPLAN = PLSQL.acidplan
                            INNER JOIN 
                                Solicitud S
                                    ON 
                                        S.ANTITSOL = C.TITULO
                            INNER JOIN 
                                Cliente CL 
                                    ON 
                                        S.ANDNICLI = CL.andnicli
    
    WHERE               MONTH(FechaVencimiento) = @int_mes
                        AND YEAR(FechaVencimiento) = @int_ano       
                        AND (
                                C.Forma IN('E', 'D', 'P', 'T') 
                                OR 
                                C.CobPor IN('00086', '00097')
                            )

    SELECT              *
                        , (SELECT SUM(Int_CantidadClientesEfectivo + Int_CantidadClientesDeposito + Int_CantidadClientesPagoFacil + Int_CantidadClientesDebito + Int_CantidadClientesTarjetaNaranja + Int_CantidadClientesPagos360) FROM #TempTipoPagosCantidad) AS TotalClientes
                        , (SELECT SUM(Int_CantidadTitulosEfectivo + Int_CantidadTitulosDeposito + Int_CantidadTitulosPagoFacil + Int_CantidadTitulosDebito + Int_CantidadTitulosTarjetaNaranja + Int_CantidadTitulosPagos360) FROM #TempTipoPagosCantidad) AS TotalTitulos

    FROM #TempTipoPagosCantidad

    DROP TABLE          #TempTipoPagosCantidad
END

Segundo SP:
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_L_ReportePagosElectronicos_Prueba]
    @int_mes INT, 
    @int_ano INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE            #TempTipoPagosCantidad  (
                                                        STRING_TipoPago CHAR(5)
                                                        , BIGINT_IdCliente INT
                                                        , FLOAT_Importe FLOAT
                                                        , BIGINT_Titulos INT
                                                    );

    INSERT INTO             #TempTipoPagosCantidad   (
                                                        STRING_TipoPago
                                                        , BIGINT_IdCliente
                                                        , FLOAT_Importe
                                                        , BIGINT_Titulos
                                                    )
   
   SELECT 
                                                        CASE 
                                                            WHEN C.Forma = 'E' THEN 'E'
                                                            WHEN C.Forma = 'D' THEN 'D'
                                                            WHEN C.Forma = 'P' THEN 'P'
                                                            WHEN C.Forma = 'T' THEN 'T'
                                                            WHEN C.CobPor = '00086' THEN '00086'
                                                            WHEN C.CobPor = '00097' THEN '00097'
                                                        END AS STRING_TipoPago
                                                        , CL.Id AS BIGINT_IdCliente
                                                        , C.IMPCOMPROB AS FLOAT_Importe
                                                        , C.TITULO AS BIGINT_Titulos
    FROM    
                                                        CUESOLIC C
                                                            INNER JOIN PLANsql PLSQL 
                                                                ON C.CODPLAN = PLSQL.acidplan
                                                            INNER JOIN Solicitud S 
                                                                ON S.ANTITSOL = C.TITULO
                                                            INNER JOIN Cliente CL 
                                                                ON S.ANDNICLI = CL.andnicli
    WHERE 
                                                        MONTH(FechaVencimiento) = @int_mes
                                                        AND YEAR(FechaVencimiento) = @int_ano        
                                                        AND (
                                                            C.Forma IN ('E', 'D', 'P', 'T') 
                                                            OR C.CobPor IN ('00086', '00097')
                                                        )

    
    SELECT                                              CASE 
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = 'E' THEN 'EFECTIVO'
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = 'D' THEN 'DEPÓSITO'
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = 'P' THEN 'PAGO FÁCIL'
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = 'T' THEN 'PAGOS 360'
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = '00086' THEN 'D. AUTOMÁTICO'
                                                            WHEN STRING_TipoPago = '00097' THEN 'T. NARANJA'
                                                        END AS STRING_TipoPago
                                                        , COUNT(DISTINCT BIGINT_IdCliente)
                                                        , SUM(FLOAT_Importe)
                                                        , COUNT(BIGINT_TituloS)

    FROM                                                #TempTipoPagosCantidad
    GROUP BY                                            STRING_TipoPago
    ORDER BY                                            STRING_TipoPago

    DROP TABLE #TempTipoPagosCantidad;
END

A la hora de ejecutarlos me devuelven:

(Acomodé los datos para que sean de fácil compresión)
Como se ve en la imagen, los dos campos que no coinciden son TN y Débito. El segundo Sp no me devuelve de manera correcta esos dos campos. ¿Alguien puede ver cuál es mi error?
Desde ya, muchas gracias

El diseño de las tablas es diferente, el cálculo es diferente, el manejo de nulos es diferente, hay calculos de totales diferentes... (TotalClientes, TotalTitulos) no están presentes en el segundo SP. Hay muchas diferencias para ambos SP. Supondría que el que manda, es el más completo, que es el primero no? y el segundo es el que se está desarrollando?

En efecto, @Excorpion el primero es el correcto y el segundo es el que se está desarrollando. Para ser tan diferentes, se asemejan bastante los resultados obviando las dos excepciones

El problema puede ser que estás usando 2 columnas distintas para las condiciones. Eso quiere decir que tus clientes Débito y Tarjeta Naranja están usando una forma de pago como efectivo, depósito, pago fácil o pagos 360.
Lo que tienes que hacer, es duplicar las filas que tienen tanto Forma IN ('E', 'D', 'P', 'T') como CobPor IN ('00086', '00097'). Esto lo puedes hacer con un JOIN hacia una tabla virtual.
Aquí está un ejemplo de como lo haría sin necesidad de usar tablas temporales.
WITH cteTiposPagos AS(
    SELECT TipoPago
         , STRING_TipoPago
    FROM ( VALUES( 'E'    , 'EFECTIVO'), 
                 ( 'D'    , 'DEPÓSITO'), 
                 ( 'P'    , 'PAGO FÁCIL'), 
                 ( 'T'    , 'PAGOS 360'), 
                 ( '00086', 'D. AUTOMÁTICO'), 
                 ( '00097', 'T. NARANJA'))TP(TipoPago, STRING_TipoPago)
)
    SELECT  TP.STRING_TipoPago
          , COUNT( DISTINCT CL.Id) AS BIGINT_IdCliente
          , SUM( C.IMPCOMPROB)     AS FLOAT_Importe
          , COUNT( C.TITULO)       AS BIGINT_Titulos
    FROM        CUESOLIC      C
    INNER JOIN  PLANsql       PLSQL ON C.CODPLAN   = PLSQL.acidplan
    INNER JOIN  Solicitud     S     ON S.ANTITSOL  = C.TITULO
    INNER JOIN  Cliente       CL    ON S.ANDNICLI  = CL.andnicli
    INNER JOIN  cteTiposPagos TP    ON TP.TipoPago IN( C.Forma, C.CobPor)
    WHERE MONTH(FechaVencimiento) = @int_mes
    AND YEAR(FechaVencimiento) = @int_ano
    AND (C.Forma IN ('E', 'D', 'P', 'T') 
         OR 
         C.CobPor IN ('00086', '00097'))
GROUP BY STRING_TipoPago
ORDER BY STRING_TipoPago;


Muchísimas gracias, estaba ignorando completamente el tema de las formas de pago para DA y TN
